# Strange behaviour with Fulltext search in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, full-text-search, contains

I have MyTable with a Column Message NVARCHAR(MAX).

Record with ID 1 contains the Message '0123456789333444 Test'

When I run the following query

```
DECLARE @Keyword NVARCHAR(100)

SET @Keyword = '0123456789000001*'

SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE CONTAINS(Message, @Keyword)
```

Record ID 1 is showing up in the results and in my opinion it should not because 0123456789333444 does not contains 0123456789000001.

Can someone explain why the records is showing up anyway?

**EDIT**

```
select * from sys.dm_fts_parser('"0123456789333444 Test"',1033,0,0)
```

returns the following:

```
group_id phrase_id occurrence special_term  display_term        expansion_type source_term
1        0         1           Exact Match  0123456789333444    0              0123456789333444 Test
1        0         1           Exact Match  nn0123456789333444  0              0123456789333444 Test
1        0         2           Exact Match  test                0              0123456789333444 Test
```

Comment: This looks very similar to [Contains() function falters with strings of numbers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8011044/contains-function-falters-with-strings-of-numbers)

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this in SQL Server 2012, with and without a stoplist. Which version are you running, what's your stoplist (I know you said it's not a factor but still I'm curious), and what is the full Message value which contains "0123456789333444"?

Comment: Hi @Keith and thanks for having a look at it. I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2. The Full Message is like above: '0123456789333444 Test'. What you mean by "what's your stoplist" ? Thanks Giuseppe

Comment: @gsharp In SSMS right-click the table, select Full-Text Index > Properties, and let us know what the value of "Full-Text Index Stoplist" is.

Comment: I'm starting to think this is an issue with SS 2008 since I'm unable to reproduce this in SS 2012, and the thread @Love2Learn linked to also concerns SS 2008. Unfortunately I can't verify this since I don't have SS 2008 installed.

Comment: Please report output of this query: `select * from sys.dm_fts_parser('"0123456789333444 Test"',1033,0,0)`

Comment: @Stoleg updated the questions with the result. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution that works. I've added `language 1033` as an additional parameter.

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE CONTAINS(Message, @Keyword, langauge 1033)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because the @Keyword is not wrapped in double quotes.  Which forces zero, one, or more matches.

> Specifies a match of words or phrases beginning with
>   the specified text. Enclose a prefix term in double quotation marks
>   ("") and add an asterisk (*) before the ending quotation mark, so that
>   all text starting with the simple term specified before the asterisk
>   is matched. The clause should be specified this way: CONTAINS (column,
>   '"text*"'). The asterisk matches zero, one, or more characters (of the
>   root word or words in the word or phrase). If the text and asterisk
>   are not delimited by double quotation marks, so the predicate reads
>   CONTAINS (column, 'text*'), full-text search considers the asterisk as
>   a character and searches for exact matches to text*. The full-text
>   engine will not find words with the asterisk (*) character because
>   word breakers typically ignore such characters.
>
> When  is a phrase, each word contained in the phrase is
>   considered to be a separate prefix. Therefore, a query specifying a
>   prefix term of "local wine*" matches any rows with the text of "local
>   winery", "locally wined and dined", and so on.

Have a look at the MSDN on the topic.  [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried to use SET @Keyword = '"0123456789000001*"' but the result is unfortunately the same.

Comment: Could you please post your DDL for the FullText Index creation.  I'd like to take a look at that if possible.

Comment: It's no big magic: ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON [dbo].[MyTable] ADD ([Message])

Comment: Can you please try removing the asterisk. I re-read the MSDN documentation again today and I consulted my Microsoft Exam book on the topic too. I'd like to see what the behavior is without it. I don't have a box I can run fulltext tests for you on otherwise I would be doing that. Hopefully the comments are helping you get at a solution. This is one of those good problems that stumps you for a bit. So it would be : SELECT...WHERE CONTAINS(Message, @Keyword). The @Keyword would be set to '"0123456789000001"'.  Notice no esterisk which from the snippet above states "zero, one, or more".

Comment: Does it work if you use this string directly, without variable?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to query the following view to see what's on the system stoplist?

```
select * from sys.fulltext_system_stopwords where language_id = 1033;
```

Comment: the usual suspects, but the stopwords are disabled on my table.